# How to make an Interface with Generic type and inheritance of Android Fragment?

Tags: java, android, generics, android-fragments

I'm developing an Android project with an Activity and some Fragments. The idea is: When the activity is launched it shows the Fragment A, and when the user click on Fragment A button, the activity should replace the Fragment A, whit a new instance of Fragment B, I would like to make the fragments completly independent of the host Activity, as a modular fragments.

So I wanna to implement a simple interface that help me to change the current fragment on the activity to another. In the interface I have create a single method that could manage a FragmentTransaction for any object type inheritance of Fragment class, but  I'm little lost with this issue, I have searched and read much documentation but I couldn't get a clear answer about this. I not sure how to do it. I have some code but it's incorrect or incomplete

Here is my interface for my Fragment A:

```
public interface ActivityInterface {
    void replaceFragment(int fragmentId, <? extends Fragment> fragment);
}
```

this would be the Activity implementation:

```
public class MyActivity  implements ActivityInterface {

    public void  replaceFragment(int fragmentId, <? extends Fragment> fragment) {
        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        fragmentTransaction.replace(fragmentId, fragment);
        fragmentTransaction.commit();
    }

}
```

- How can I get it working?
- Is there a better solution for this?

I am a novice in 'Java Generics' topic so please be clear, I'd appreciate a lot.

Comment: This is what you exactly have to do: http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html

Answer (score 1):

I believe you are looking for this:

```
public interface ActivityInterface {
    <T extends Fragment> void replaceFragment(int fragmentId, T fragment);
}

public class MyActivity  implements ActivityInterface {

    public <T extends Fragment> void replaceFragment(int fragmentId, T fragment) {
        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        fragmentTransaction.replace(fragmentId, fragment);
        fragmentTransaction.commit();
    }
}
```

(although technically I think that'd work just fine with merely `void replaceFragment(int fragmentId, Fragment fragment);`)

Comment: The question is pretty confusing if you go to think of it. It doesn't require the use of generics at all as you rightly pointed out :)